# How to pass flags to the node binary when using Npm's bin feature

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm writing a little Npm package that has a `package.json#bin` field pointing to one of my scripts.

```json
{
  "name": "myBin",
  "bin": ".dist/cli.js",
  "main": ".dist/cli.js"
}
```

I now need to run the script with Node's `--loader` (or `--experimental-loader`) flag to support loading TypeScript plugins.

I can't put the flag in to the `scripts` field directly because these flags need to come **before** my script name (as handled by Npm).

```json
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-npm": "myBin ...",
    "dev-node": "node --loader esbuild-register/loader node_modules/myBin ..."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "myBin": "*"
  }
}
```

*Note: An earlier version of this question included the mistaken assertion that Node could take the flags it needed after my script's name.*

Is there any way to include that `--loader` flag that I need, or other `node` flags, when calling `node` via Npm?

I guess I could call `node --loader ...` as a subprocess of the parent `node` inside of `myBin`, making `myBin` a wrapper for `node --loader ... myBin`, but that seems suboptimal.

Comment: Its _your_ binary file, why does it _depend_ on a flag? Just rewrite it so it doesn't need that flag maybe?

Comment: No. It's my `cli.js`. Npm is calling `node .dist/cli.js` for me. I need to pass an argument to `node` to enable a feature that is only enable-able by invocation flag.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of a better option, I'm moving forward with the self-relaunching option.
It's not perfect, but gets the job done.

```js
import { fork } from 'child_process';

if (!process.execArgv.includes('--experimental-loader')) {
  // Get the node binary, file, and non-node arguments that we ran with
  const [nodeBin, module, ...args] = process.argv;

  // Re-running with esbuild-register loader
  fork(module, args, {
    execArgv: [
      // Get the arguments passed to the node binary
      ...process.execArgv,
      // Pass more arguments to node binary as desired
      '--experimental-loader',
      'esbuild-register/loader',
      '--require',
      'esbuild-register',
    ],
  }).once('close', process.exit);
} else {
  // Normal operation
}
```